# Is there a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer for <portlet-preferences>?

Tags: spring, portlet, preferences

I understand that there is the [`ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) which:

> resolves placeholders as ServletContext init parameters (that is, web.xml context-param entries).

Does anyone know of a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` that would similarly resolve placeholders as `portlet-preferences` (that is, `portlet.xml` `portlet-preference` entries)?

Comment: Did you ever find how to do this?

Comment: Sadly, no. I ended up creating a bean with a getPortletPreference method. I then use this bean in my spring config to define preference values as beans - which I can use throughout my spring config. So far, it's working quite well for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem, I ended up writing a class similar to ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.. :-)

```
public class PortletConfigPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer implements PortletConfigAware {

    private PortletConfig portletConfig;

    private boolean configOverride = false;

    public void setPortletConfig(PortletConfig portletConfig) {
        this.portletConfig = portletConfig;
    }

    public void setConfigOverride(boolean configOverride) {
        this.configOverride = configOverride;
    }

    @Override
    protected String resolvePlaceholder(String placeholder, Properties props) {
        String value = null;
        if (this.configOverride && this.portletConfig != null) {
            value = resolvePlaceholder(placeholder, this.portletConfig);
        }
        if (value == null) {
            value = super.resolvePlaceholder(placeholder, props);
        }
        return value;
    }

    protected String resolvePlaceholder(String placeholder,
            PortletConfig portletConfig) {
        return portletConfig.getInitParameter(placeholder);
    }
}
```

Cheers,
Gerson